# How to solve gem conflict error? - Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Trying to run `gem install slickgrid-rails` it shows:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyResolutionError)
>       conflicting dependencies actionpack (~> 3.1.0) and actionpack (= 3.0.0)   Activated actionpack-3.0.0   which does not match conflicting dependency (~> 3.1.0)
>
> Conflicting dependency chains:
>
> ```
> slickgrid-rails (>= 0), 0.3.1 activated, depends on
> railties (~> 3.0), 3.0.0 activated, depends on
> actionpack (= 3.0.0), 3.0.0 activated
> ```
>
> versus:
>
> ```
> slickgrid-rails (>= 0), 0.3.1 activated, depends on
> sass-rails (>= 0), 3.1.0 activated, depends on
> actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
> ```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe this will work `bundle exec gem install slickgrid-rails`.

Comment: just tried this and does not works.  :[

Answer (score 0):

Add `slickgrid-rails` to your Gemfile, then run `bundle install`.

Comment: Not work yet, Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    slickgrid-rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
      railties (~> 3.0) ruby

    rails (= 4.2.0) ruby depends on
      railties (4.2.0)

Comment: It looks like `slickgrid-rails` is not compatible with your version of Rails (4.2.0). Slickgrid depends on railties 3.x, but you have 4.2.0.